# Relationships in Entity Framework Core zero to one

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following tables and is not sure how to configure this setup regarding EF Core:

I have a table (UserTable) that can have a foreign key to either one table or another.

**AdminTable**
int AdminTableId

**RegularUserTable**
int RegularUserTableId

**UserTable** 
int UserTableId

int AdminTableId (nullable) FK
int RegularUserTableId (nullable) FK

Comment: On your user table class use int? Example: public int? AdminTableId;.  This makes them nullable and will correctly translate to the SQL tables.